# Web Service in Python

Tags: php, python, django, web-services

I installed rapidsms in local for send messages. The application tested with local server. Now i would like to store the incoming messages in another database via a php application. Means when a message received in rapidsms (Django-Python) app, i want to call a php application function and store message in php app database. For this which method is best?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [python-suds](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds) to communicate via WSDL with your PHP app.
IMHO the best option would be to [inspect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) the PHP database and directly store the data from python. Low latency and no overhead.

Comment: Here when i receive a message in rapidsms application, i want to call  php function. Is it possible with python-suds?

Comment: Suds is a SOAP Client. You need to create a SOAP-API on your PHP side. If the PHP script is on the same machine and you simply want to call it you could use `subprocess` http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I'm newbie in python and this comment not well clear to me. Can you explain more briefly?